# How to resolve MassTransit Mediator "some services are not able to be constructed" for request client

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm having a look at MassTransit, and I used the masstransit dotnet temaplate to generate a worker, as per  https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/  ( everything up till RabbitMQ )

Then I was interested in getting the built in mediator working with responses, so changed the code according to https://masstransit-project.com/articles/mediator.html

so it the setup looks like ...

```
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddMediator(x =>
                    {
                        x.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();
                        x.AddRequestClient<Message>();
                    });
                    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                    {
                        x.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<MessageConsumer>();

                        x.UsingInMemory((context,cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                        });
                    });
                    services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
                    
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
```

and the consumer / contract now looks like

```
public class Message { public string Text { get; set; } }
public class MessageResult { public string Text { get; set; } }
public class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
{
    readonly ILogger<MessageConsumer> _logger;

    public MessageConsumer(ILogger<MessageConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Received Text: {Text}", context.Message.Text);
        return context.RespondAsync(new MessageResult() {Text = $"Got {context.Message.Text}"});
    }
}
```

and the worker looks like

```
  public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly IBus _bus;
        private readonly IRequestClient<Message> _request;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IBus bus, IRequestClient<Message> request)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _bus = bus;
            _request = request;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var response = await _request.GetResponse<MessageResult>(new Message {Text = $"The time is {DateTimeOffset.Now}"}, stoppingToken);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

however when I run it, the injection of IRequestClient seems to fail ( for some reason it wasn't registered? )  with the exception

```
Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: MTGettingStarted.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'MassTransit.IRequestClient`1[MTGettingStarted.Message]' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.
```

Which is what I thought `x.AddRequestClient<Message>();` should have done.  Maybe the documentation is incomplete? or I missed something?

If I change the worker to manaully get the request, then it does work

```
        var client = _mediator.CreateRequestClient<Message>();
        var response = await client.GetResponse<MessageResult>(new Message {Text = $"The time is {DateTimeOffset.Now}"}, stoppingToken);
```

But still curious why the DI doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IRequestClient<T>` is registered in the container as scoped, which the error you posted indicates:

`Cannot consume scoped service`

Your hosted service is a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sample working you have to enable your worker to use scoped services.

Take a look at the docs at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

In the implementation behind `IScopedProcessingService` you have to inject `IRequestClient<>`.

```cs
private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var scopedProcessingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

        await scopedProcessingService.DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```